# In a deep neural network loss decreases significantly once I increase the number of fully connected layers

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, image-classification

I am training a ViT based classification model and trying to study the behaviour of the model by increasing the number of fc layers. One thing that I noticed that if I increase the fc layers beyond 2, loss decreases significantly only after a few iterations while with one or two fc layers, loss curve appears smoother and decreases slowly. I am adding the loss curves for your reference (left: 3 layers, right: 2 layers)

[image][image]

I have read that increasing the number of layers can cause more training accuracy but at the same time, it might overfit. But by looking at the loss curve, it doesn't appear to be overfitting (number of neurons in one fc layer: 1000)

Can someone explain this behaviour? Thanks in advance

Comment: You're not comparing the two graphs on the same scale (25 epochs vs 15 epochs) so what you're observing is not 'speed'. Another thing is that adding more fc layers doesn't always cause overfitting, that only happens when we don't use regularization or when the task is in high dimensions (computer vision) etc.

Comment: @IlyasMoutawwakil, I agree that adding fc layers doesn't always cause overfitting if trained in a constrained environment. What I am trying to understand here is that is model learning faster when the number of fc layer is increased (as it can be observed in the graphs)? I have stopped the first graph at 15 epoch, the reason being that the loss had already decreased and there were no significant improvement in the same.